# Windows 10 disable Aero Snapping

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, gui

I apologize if there is proper verbiage for what Windows 10 is doing.  I press Windows-Right and it pushes the focus window to the right half of its current screen, like it did in 7.  But it also sprays all of the other windows across the open half, so that nothing can be read from them until I click again.  It's very distracting.  I just want the rest of the windows to stay where they are.  How do I stop it from spraying Windows all over the place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!  The magic word is "Snap".  The OS is Snapping the windows to the side, and then helpfully showing which windows to choose from.  I've disable the "suggest companion windows" in Settings->System->Multitasking to fix it.
http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-disable-snap-assist-windows-10/

Comment: In 2019, the setting is now called "When I snap a window, show what I can snap next to it".