# Disable edge snapping on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is there any way to disable edge snapping in Windows 10?
By edge snapping I mean the window feature where windows snap and resize when dragging it's edges near the taskbar or desktop edges.

[image: Edge snapping]

Brownie points if someone knows how to disable it without disabling window snapping (dragging the whole window to an edge for resizing and layout).

Comment: [How to Disable Snap Assist in Windows 10](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-disable-snap-assist-windows-10/)

Comment: [How to Turn On or Off Aero Snap in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4343-aero-snap-turn-off-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Edge Snap" but see if the above links help.

Comment: Similar question / answer : https://superuser.com/questions/1065062/windows-10-disable-window-spray

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want to disable aero snap entirely, only edge snapping. I explained what the term is in my question and included a screenshot. Specifics, people.

Comment: I want snap assist, just not the edge feature.

Comment: Since this question applies to a function within Windows 10 (and not Windows as a whole), I added the appropriate tag.  Specifics, Francisco.  ;-)

Comment: "Francisco", specifics, Run5k ;)

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to.  ;-)